# polynomial maps

Tags: polynomials

A prolongation of the question
[composition-of-polynomial-functions-which-gives-the-identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83745/composition-of-polynomial-functions-which-gives-the-identity):
Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n, g_1,\ldots, g_n$ be polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that if $g=(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ then $f_i(g(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=x_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Does it follow that SOME $f_i$ or $g_j$ has degree 1?

Comment: @ Mahdi Majidi-Zolbanin - Of course, $n>1$.

Comment: @Boris: Sorry I deleted my comment, because even though the answer to your question is yes for $n=1$, your question still makes sense without saying $n>1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course not. For example, consider the automorphism of $\mathbb Q[x, y]$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto (x+y^2, y + (x+y^2)^2)$.

Comment: Is it really necessary to start an answer with an "of course"?

Comment: Of course not, is it?

Comment: Of course it is not necessary; but when you start playing around with automorphisms of polynomial rings you discover these examples very quickly.

Comment: @ Angelo - in your example $g_2=y$?

Comment: @Boris: no. The inverse map is given by $(x-(y-x^2)^2,y-x^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to say what Angelo said.  Pick any set of polynomials $\left(g_1,\ldots,g_n\right)$ such that it has [Groebner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) $\left[x_1,\ldots,x_n\right]$ under [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) $\left[x_n,\ldots,x_1\right]$.  Then you can get the $f_j$'s [from the cofactors](http://math.mit.edu/~ssam/writings/reu08.pdf) (pdf).

[This is merely a more constructive way of phrasing the answer, so that you may construct more examples for yourself easily, which is not as easy to do given Angelo's answer.]

Comment: Is it true then, that every $f_i$ and every $g_i$ must have a degree $1$ term?

Comment: @Mahdi: yes on both counts.  Easy proof by contradiction and combinatorics -- just look at the (total) degrees of each term in the result.

Comment: To Mahdi: or, more geometrically, notice that if some $f_i$ had no term of degree, the differential of the polynomial map given by the $f_i$ would would vanish at some point.

Comment: @ Jacques Carette - Your answer is too laconic for me

Comment: @Boris: added links for all the important parts.  If you don't already know about Groebner bases, you're better off reading the Wikipedia entry than having me try to expand my answer into a tutorial on the topic.

Comment: @ Jacques: Thank you. I know what is Grobner basis. What I needed, was a reference with cofactors. Now I will parse.